# trying to convert a string to char useing .substr

Tags: c++, string, char, data-conversion

i'm trying to turn a 1d array of strings into a 2d array of chars using:

```
    '''''''''''''''
    variables
    '''''''''''''''
    const int width = 20;
    const int height = 20;  
    char arena[width][height];
    string arenaline[height];

    '''''''''''''''
    setup
    '''''''''''''''
    arenaline[1] = "####################";
    arenaline[2] = "#..................#";
    arenaline[3] = "#..................#";
    arenaline[4] = "###...###..###...###";
    arenaline[5] = "#.......#..#.......#";
    arenaline[6] = "###...###..###...###";
    arenaline[7] = "#..................#";
    arenaline[8] = "###...###..###...###";
    arenaline[9] = "#.......#..#.......#";
    arenaline[10] = "#########..#########";
    arenaline[11] = "###..............###";
    arenaline[12] = "###.#####..#####.###";
    arenaline[13] = "###.####....####.###";
    arenaline[14] = "###.####....####.###";
    arenaline[15] = "#.....###..###.....#";
    arenaline[16] = "#.....###..###.....#";
    arenaline[17] = "#..#..###..###..#..#";
    arenaline[18] = "#.....###..###.....#";
    arenaline[19] = "#.....###..###.....#";
    arenaline[20] = "####################";

    '''''''''''''''
    conversion
    '''''''''''''''
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {

        arena[j][i] = arenaline[i].substr(j,1);

    }

}
```

I want it to convert from the substring to a char so I can use it in an array.

I can't use a string instead of chars because it breaks the function where the array is output to the console.

Comment: Why not change the function that doesn't work with `std::string` to work with `std::string`?

Comment: Also don't forget that array indexes are zero-based (so your initialization is wrong, and would not work anyway as shown) and that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** byte string*, and you need space for that terminator as well if you ever want to use the C string functions with the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) returns a string. string is not implicitly converted to char for "single character" strings.

The correct way to adress single characters of strings is string::operator[] or string::at().